# Catch JIT Errors in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, error-handling

I am trying to write any errors out our users receive in a vb.net application to a log file and I was wondering if there is any way to catch JIT errors and if so what is the code to do this?

Thanks

Comment: So, JIT exceptions... do these not only occur during debugging? I don't have to debug much so I really am not 100% familiar with all the terms. The exceptions you speak of are different than what a Catch will catch within a tryblock?

Comment: No some even occur only during runtime, and not during debugging. The only thing to do is to enclose them in a try catch https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/try-catch-finally-statement

Comment: @nbk Please explain "only during runtime, and not during debugging".

Comment: @Mr.Tripodi "I don't have to debug much" Lucky you.

Comment: During Form Load, if an error occurs, the debug modus ends the Foemloading process and you can click on buttons and so on without interrupting the running process. At runtime(running the exe direct) you get an runtime error. i write mostly mdi forms, so i cannot tell if it is a mdi Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what nbk is saying, you could do something like this

```
Private Sub LogEx()
    Try
        'Some stuff that will fail
    Catch ex As Exception
        LogException(Environment.UserName, ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub LogException(ByVal Username As String, Ex As String)
    Dim LogFilePath As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\MyLog.txt"

    Dim MyLogFile As IO.StreamWriter =
        My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(LogFilePath , True)
    MyLogFile.WriteLine(Username & "---" & Ex)
    MyLogFile.Close()
End Sub
```